# Any drug interactions between Ginkgo Biloba and psychotropics?

Tags: mental-health, depression, anxiety-disorders, drug-interactions, antidepressants

What are the interactions, if any, and their effects to mood/health/wellness, between [Ginkgo Biloba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginkgo_biloba#Health) and psychotropics?

I'm interested in answers covering at least these drug types:

- Selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors (SSRI) - example: Fluoxetine (Prozac)
- Serotonin–norepinephrine reuptake inhibitors (SNRI) - example: Desvenlafaxine (Pristiq)
- Dopamine reuptake inhibitors - example: Methylphenidate (Ritalin, Concerta)

**Update:** I tried using drug interaction checkers, such as that from [Medscape](https://reference.medscape.com/drug-interactionchecker), but no interactions are reported. Nevertheless, I've done some online search and found some informal references (aka: Reddit) saying that Ginkgo Biloba is a [MAOI (monoamine oxidase inhibitor)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoamine_oxidase_inhibitor). It is generally advised not to take other medication such as antidepressants and stimulants if you have been on a MAOI for the past 14 days (or vice versa) due to the increased risk of serotonin syndrome, possibly fatal.

I found [one study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23538078) stating:

> Potential interactions with monoamine oxidase inhibitors, alprazolam,
>   haloperidol, warfarin, and nifedipine have been reported in case studies.

It also says that no changes in MAO A or B levels were observed, in one study using positron emission tomography imaging following 1 month of treatment at 120mg/day of Ginkgo Biloba in humans; although this might be due to the comparatively low dosage.

Comment: What have you learned so far in your own research?

Comment: Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you are not sure how to conduct your own research for a question about pharmacological interactions, say so in your question. Thanks! // P.S. It is an interesting question, I just want to make sure you don't get downvotes or put on hold for not following the guidelines.

Comment: @MarkDWorthenPsyD Thanks for the friendly heads-up. I'll soon be working to improve the question.

Comment: Many drug interaction checkers include supplements. Ex: http://reference.medscape.com/drug-interactionchecker

Comment: +1 because this is a good question now that you have added evidence of prior research